# How to serialize a nested (generic) case class

Tags: scala, json4s

Looking for some help on serializing a nested case object using json4s. The wrinkle is that the case object is decided at runtime, so it seems I'd need access to the outer formatters? e.g

```
trait Base { val id: Long }
case class ChildA(id: Long, name:String) extends Base
case class ChildB(id: Long, name:String) extends Base
case class WithTimestamp[E <: Base](base:E, timestamp:Long)
```

now, if I serialize a WithTimestamp I get, e.g

```
{"base":{"id":1, "name":"foo"}, timestamp:12345 }
```

but what I'd like to get is:

```
{"id":1, "name":"foo", timestamp:12345 }
```

which would seem to require a custom serializer:

```
class WithTimestampSerializer[E <: Base] extends CustomSerializer[WithTimestamp[E]](
  f => ( {
    case x: JObject => ... 

  }, {
    case x: WithTimestamp[E] =>
    val j: JValue = write(x.base) // <--- not sure what to do at this point,
                                  // i.e. write either the ChildA or ChildB default serialization
      j merge JObject("timestamp" -> JLong(x.timestamp))
  }))
```

How do I get access to the formatter at that point, which should be available?

Comment: I think you want to use Extraction.decompose(x.base). And you probably can skip variance and replace `WithTimestamp[E]` with `WithTimestamp[_]`. I would also consider changing/creating the model used for serving data. Might be simpler in the long run than custom formatters.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but that still flags me as requiring an implicit formatter, which seems to just push the problem back 1 level. Adding an implicit formatter gives me a stack overflow, obv. creating a circular reference of some kind.

Comment: Oh, you need something like `implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats + new WithTimestampSerializer` visible to your serializer. Or you could just pass `f` to decompose(...)(f) instead of using implicits.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks

Comment: @TomerShetah I considered it and added an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The serializer would look like this:

```
class WithTimestampSerializer extends CustomSerializer[WithTimestamp[_]](
  f => ( {
    case x: JObject => ???
  }, {
    case x: WithTimestamp[_] =>
      val j: JValue = Extraction.decompose(x.base)(f) // <- the important part
      j merge JObject("timestamp" -> JLong(x.timestamp))
  }))
```

You can either use `Extraction.decompose(x.base)(f)` or have an implicit of type `Format` nearby.

However, if you'll want to deserialize it or grow the project, I would recommend adding a new case class just for the purpose of modeling JSON data. It adds some repetition but can be easier to maintain.